# Acessing class on different namespace without redeclare it

Tags: c#, visual-studio, class

I just moving to C# previously I'm using visual basic programming
I'm not familiar with static void, internal in C#, oke just to the point

I have 2 cs file of namespace it is class 1 and class 2

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    log_lib.Log log = new log_lib.Log(2, 0, true, true);
    SockBase base2 = new SockBase(log);
    ProcessPacket packet = new ProcessPacket("configfile.cfg");
}
```

and

```
public class Echo : WebSocketBehavior
{
    protected override void OnMessage(MessageEventArgs e)
    {
          var name = Context.QueryString["name"];
          var msg = !name.IsNullOrEmpty() ? String.Format("{0}", e.Data, name) : e.Data;
          Send(msg);
          packet.DoTheFunction(msg)  <<< This is error
          Console.WriteLine(msg);
          Class1.smethod_0();
    }
}
```

In visual basic, I just define variable and any class thing as global or public variable, but why on c# class packet couldn't be accesible in class 2?
I already make sure include class1 in class2 by doing 
using Class1;

**The question is, how to I acces .packet in Class1 from Class2?**

Comment: Please provide the whole code for your `Class1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Variables in C# are *scoped*. Scopes are created by `{}` so:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    log_lib.Log log = new log_lib.Log(2, 0, true, true);
    SockBase base2 = new SockBase(log);
    ProcessPacket packet = new ProcessPacket("configfile.cfg");
}
```

Has a variable called `packet` that is scoped to the `Main` function. You can't access it outside that scope. If you made it a class property by doing this:

```
public static ProcessPacket Packet {get; set;} //Expose properties, not fields!
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    log_lib.Log log = new log_lib.Log(2, 0, true, true);
    SockBase base2 = new SockBase(log);
    Packet = new ProcessPacket("configfile.cfg");
}
```

Then you have a *class* scoped member called `Packet`, and you can now do:

```
Class1.Packet
```

Anywhere else to access it, or in C# 6:

```
using static Class1; //Why are you doing this!!!

public void someMethod()
{
    Paket.DoSomething(); //Example call so it made sense
}
```

Note that this isn't really what they introduced static usings for, I would *not* use one here (or really, `static` in general until you know what you are doing, but I digress).

Also note that depending on how you set up the code using the `Packet` static member you may get `NullReferenceException` if you try to use it before `Main` sets it.

Answer (score 3):

Just for my amusement tell me somebody, why the original question is being downvoted?

Here are some issue, first namespace and visibility.

Two classes see each other as long as they are in the same namespace:

```
namespace MyNameSpace
{
    class FirstClass
    {
    }

    class SecondClass
    {
        public DoSomething()
        {
             FirstClass first = new FirstClass();
        }
    }
}
```

Same result, both classes see each other:

```
//FirstClass.cs
namespace MyNameSpace
{
    class FirstClass
    {
    }
}

//SecondClass.cs
namespace MyNameSpace
{
    class SecondClass
    {
        public DoSomething()
        {
             FirstClass first = new FirstClass();
        }
    }
}
```

Same result, both classes see each other in different namespaces:

```
//FirstClass.cs
namespace FirstNameSpace
{
    class FirstClass
    {
    }
}

//SecondClass.cs
using FirstNameSpace; //this only makes FirstClass visible inside this file
namespace SecondNameSpace
{
    class SecondClass
    {
        public DoSomething()
        {
             FirstClass first = new FirstClass();
        }
    }
}
```

**They can see each other, but, they can not access each others data!**

Now next issue is, that you for some reason want to access some data inside FirstClass from SecondClass, or even from somewhere else. To do so, there are multiple ways to accomplish such task, but first you have to see instance of the class:

FirstClass will remember last instance in static field:

```
namespace MyNameSpace
{
    class FirstClass
    {
        public static FirstClass last_instance;
        public string some_public_data;
        public FirstClass()
        {
            this.some_public_data = "some data";
            last_instance= this;
            //keeps last created instance
        }
    }

    class SecondClass
    {
        public DoSomethingWithFirstClass()
        {
             FirstClass first_class = FirstClass.last_instance;
             Console.WriteLine(first_class.some_public_data);
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
         static void Main()
         {
             new FirstClass();//last_instance will be stored
             SecondClass second_class = new SecondClass();
             second_class.DoSomethingWithFirstClass()
         }
    }
}
```

Now guts inside SecondClass can access last_instance of FirstClass, **but perhaps you do not need whole instance access**:

```
namespace MyNameSpace
{
    class FirstClass
    {
        public static string some_public_static_data;
        public FirstClass()
        {
            some_public_static_data = "some static data";
        }
    }

    class SecondClass
    {
        public DoSomethingWithStaticDataOfFirstClass()
        {
             Console.WriteLine(FirstClass.some_public_static_data);
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
         static void Main()
         {
             new FirstClass();//it just updates static data

             SecondClass second_class = new SecondClass();
             second_class.DoSomethingWithStaticDataOfFirstClass()
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your "singleton" is not remotely one, and your second `static` version is just a bit odd. You aren't entirely wrong here, but I worry this will just confuse the OP (or others).

Comment: You are right, it is not a complete implementation, 
I wanted to show how to store an instance of the class in the static field.More than complete singleton. It is an explanation, how to access static data between classes. The author seems to have problems with that...

Comment: No doubt. With an answer this extensive, I would probably just go with correctly instanced objects instead of dealing with static. The only reason I went with static is I didn't want to write this much (and it gets him there a bit faster) :)

Comment: I corrected code, calling it singleton was perhaps too bold:).
Perhaps it was not waste of time completely:).

Comment: I like this quite a bit better. +1!

Answer (score 0):

When you work in VB, scope is not as easy to see but still applies, so when you have an event that you are scripting, that is the scope and you can add vars to that scope and see them from any objects added to the scope.

With C#, scope is a bit more strict, but no more so than VB.  The extra step is making sure the object you are wanting to access within your class is public and is a class member, not a private member in a method.

```
public class class1 {

    public ProcessPacket packet;

    public static void maid (){
        packet = new ProcessPacket();
    }
}
```

Now packet is visible as a property of class1.  You might want to add a getter to make sure you check that packet is initialized before asking for it in another class.

Comment: This should be a public property, not a public field.

Answer (score 0):

Well,

```
ProcessPacket packet = new ProcessPacket("configfile.cfg");
```

is in the scope of your main method. As soon as the execution flow leaves the main method, `packet` is disposed of. It is impossible to reference a variable outside its scope. So you have no chance of accessing this in `Class2`. If you really want to expose this, then you will need to create a static public property of `Class1`. You can then use this in `Class2` by calling `Class1.packet`.

Comment: Of course, leaving the scope of `Main` also happens to immediately terminate the program...

Comment: Ha - sure, my bad for writing that redundancy.

Comment: Nah it redeclare the packet :D I was confusing with the scope problem , the packet not accessible from another namespace